# If $a<b+r$ for every rational $r>0$ then $a\leq b$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Show that if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b + r$ for every positive rational $r$, then $a\leq b$

I think it might be useful to use the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't really know how to approach this problem

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $a>b$. Then we can find a rational number $r$ such that $0 < r < a-b$, and then $a<b+r<a$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Draw a point on a piece of paper. Denote it by $a$. Then draw another point, somewhat to the left of $a$, and denote it by $b$. Thus, you are assuming, by way of contradiction, that $b>a$. Draw a little line between $a$ and $b$. How
do you think you can use the density of the rationals now?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose for contradiction that $a > b$. Then $a - b > 0$, so take rational $0 < r < a - b$, and we have $b + r < a$. Such an $r$ exists by density of the rationals in the reals, as you said. This contradicts the hypothesis.

Answer (score -1):

another idea is to take $r=\frac{1}{n}$ so $$a<b+\frac 1n$$ how to read inequality when $n$ tends to $+\infty$ ?